$f\subset\mathbb R^2$ is a convex function defined on a closed interval. Prove the Legendre transformation of $f$ is defined on the entire real line.
$f \subset \mathbb R^2$ is a convex function defined on a closed interval. Prove the Legendre transformation $g$ of $f$ is defined on the entire real line.

For every point $x$ in the domain of $f$, there must be a finite $f(x)$.
For each real number $p$, have a line segment $l_p$ given by $l_p(x) = px$. The scalar multiplication of each finite $x$ is also finite. The difference of any two finite points is finite. As a result, we can define a function $f - l_p$, which has a well-defined supremum over a compact set.
This induces a function $g : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, given by $g(p) = \sup(f - l_p)$. We know from the preceding steps that every $g(p)$ is finite, and so $g$ is well-defined.
QED

Outside of any deeper reference to analysis (which might be excessive), is this a clean and satisfactory way to demonstrate the property?
